# To infinitive as object complement

Tags: grammar, infinitives, to-infinitive, complements, object-complements

i have a question concerning whether "to resist" in the sentence below is an object complement.

"He lacked the strength to resist"

Comment: Apparently, *an object complement is a predicative expression that follows a direct object of an attributive ditransitive verb or resultative verb and that complements the direct object of the sentence by describing it*. So by *that* definition, your example isn't an "object complement", because ***to lack*** is nether ditransitive nor "resultative". But  the remarkably similar utterance ***He gave me the strength to resist*** does appear to match that definition. Though I can't for the life of me see how knowing the "correct" categorisation here would help anyone actually learn English.